# How to change Keyboard name in Catalina

Tags: keyboard, catalina, imac

I bought an apple wireless Bluetooth keyboard on eBay and I can't change its name to mine. I'm using the latest Catalina. Actually I can change the name thru the Bluetooth panel but the name does not stay changed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give the exact model of the Mac and and its manufacture year?

Comment: It’s an iMac 27” late 2013 model. It’s been quite a while since I tried to do this - but, what I remember is the problem is not with the computer but with the OS. Apparently, you cannot change the name of any Bluetooth hardware if you’re using any OS past Mojave. So, I remembered that my brother has the same computer as mine but he has not updated it and is still using Mavericks. I went to his house and used his computer to change the mouse and keyboard names with no problem. So, I got the job done but would like to know if there’s a work around for for later OS’s. Really aggravating!

Comment: No, I think the only way to change the bluetooth name of a keyboard or mouse is to do an old system installation (El Capitan) and change the names of bluetooth devices with that system. I wanted to offer you this method if your Mac supports El Capitan, but you have found a good solution. ;-)

Comment: How can Apple just break something like this and make no attempt to fix it? They apparently couldn’t care less and have absolutely no plans to ever fix it. Very disappointing for a company that’s supposed to have great hardware and software.